# Add another column to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

By processing the values in the 'label_A' column of the results dataframe, I have generated values shown below (12, 13, ..., 21, 23). How can I add another column to this dataframe from within these loops to store the 'unique' values. The new column should have rows like [12,13] and [16, 17], [20, 24] and [21,23]. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can't you just use apply, like `df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda r:yourfunc(*r.label_A))`?  You would have to wrap your function.

Answer (score 0):

try using dataframes concat. concat can add rows or columns to a dataframe